# what the benefit uploading hex file merely to arduino board?

Tags: arduino-ide

What the benefit of uploading merely hex file to avr based board like arduino uno Since the arduino ide it self will send intel hex file to the board after compile .ino file to hex file by the avrdude compiler (https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Build-Process)?

Comment: The data is send to the bootloader, and the bootloader writes it to flash memory. Can you explain your question? What else would you want to upload to the arduino board?

Comment: i just wondering if there is sketch speed execution difference betwen uploading .ino file and uploading pure hex file whether via usb or isp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload the same sketch to many  Arduinos compiling it again and again would take much longer. Or if you create a firmware ànd don't want to disclose the source code, you can distribute it in compiled form.

Comment: In some languages an accent can be used to emphasize a word, but the other accent is used (á). What is ànd?

Comment: @Jot, I don't know. I wrote it on an Android phone with on screen keyboard which has only English characters

Comment: i just want to know if there is significant speed difference in user program excecution between .ino file and hex file

Comment: ino file is not executable. it is a source code. an input for the compiler

Comment: @juraj i do agree with you reffer to link i attached with my question. but when you googling "send hex file to avr board" and some short of that  you will find alot talking around that concept. what dou you think

Comment: The page describes what happens when you push the Upload button in IDE. The "send hex file to avr board" is about sending a ready hex file. It is the last chapter of the "build process". What is unclear?

Comment: if the arduino ide via uart connection send hex file extracted from .ino file to arduino board after upload button pressed why so many avr anthusiast talking about send hex file to avr board like http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk

Comment: because AVR was here long before Arduino. and the multiuploads

Comment: so you are saying coding with .ino or send hex file to arduino board will result the same in term of program speed execution

Comment: the hex created from that ino will be always the same. if you write in assembler language or low level C, the hex will be different and the program possible faster.

Comment: thank you bro its clear now that asm c and ino created different hex file. again thank you.